# Swift how to add UITableView to UIViewController with custom UITableView class

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, swift

Can someone help me with next issue:

I have tried to put `UIView`, subclassed from `UITableView`, to `UIViewController` in next way:

```
class CustomTableView: UITableView, UITableVIewDelegate {
      override var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
      get {
           return self.delegate
      }
      set {
          self.delegate = newValue
      }
   }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableVIewDelegate  {
      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: CustomTableView

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          self.tableView.delegate = self
      }

      func tableView(tableView: UITableView. didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           //Not called
      }
}
```

In **IB** I put `UIView` on `UIViewController`. But app has crashed with exception in

```
set {
              self.delegate = newValue
          }
```

Someone have any idea what I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you overriding delegate? it isn't doing anything differently.

Comment: You are right. It's look like it didn't do anything. I just wanna checked what's happening when I try set delegate,because without it my didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called. Seems like ViewController didn't know about CustomTableView and I wanna know why

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual crash log.

Comment: It seems like app just going into infinite loop on "self.delegate = newValue" line and didn't gives me any error logs. Now I guess it's just a bad way to adding UITableView on UIViewController or I need implement some custom delegate for it. But I'm not sure about the last.

Comment: Isn't `self.delegate = newValue` triggering the setter, which triggers `self.delegate = newValue` etc? That looks like an infinite loop

Comment: Bob Vork, yeah. You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

self.delegate = newValue is calling its setter; which agains call its setter. It's an infinite loop.

This can be an approach to your question: 
1. Add a uitableview as a subview of your viewcontroller's view.
2. Set the viewcontroller as tableview's datasource and delegate. 
3. Then you can customize tableview according to your need.

Comment: You are right, it's an infinite loop. So i re-wrote it like this "delegate = newValue!". That must work(or not?). But I have a same problem as before.
For the second. I can't set UITableView as a subviews of ViewController, 'cause I need a UITableView with static cell and it's imposible on UIVIewController. So, I put UIView on my ViewController and inherit it from UITableView.